# Some rules are not listed when I open my GPO rules editor

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy

I need to enable a rule using a GPO's, the rule is -> Security Zones: Do not allow users to Add/Delete Sites.

The rule is located

Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Internet Explorer

But I need to configure that rule on a windows server 2003 sp2, but does not appear, but If I look on a Windows 2008 the rule it's there.

So the question is how can update my rule list on a windows server 2003?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the [client side extensions](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e60b5c8f-d7dc-4b27-a261-247ce3f6c4f8&displaylang=en) installed?

Comment: Where do I have to install it, on the server?